# onchange no envia el valor

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo un problema con AJAX, tengo un campo en HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="numreporte" name="numeroreporte" value="30" >
```

Y tengo la siguiente función:

```
function valnumreport(){

 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ruta.php',
        data:'numeroreporte='+ document.getElementById('numreporte').value,
        success:function(response){

   alert (numeroreporte);


  }
  });
}
```

Y llamo a la función con un `onchange`:

```
onchange ='valnumreport()'
```

Lo que quiero es mandar el valor del `hidden` a otra página con un evento `onchange` pero no lo envía, apenas estoy trabajando con AJAX por eso no tengo muchos conocimientos.

Comment: Intentalo asi: `data:{numeroreporte:  document.getElementById('numreporte').value}`

Comment: crea un console.log("valnumreport() called") dentor de la funcion valnumreport, asi sabrás si es que se llama o no, y detectaras si es error de onchange, o del ajax que no devuelve.

Comment: y el codigo del evento onchange?

Comment: Pero el onchange en donde está incluido? en el input hidden numreporte?, onchange solo ejecuta cuando se hace un cambio sobre ese elemento, si esta puesto sobre un hidden, nunca ejecutara el evento onchange.

Comment: como dice Roy, el onchange no funciona en un campo de tipo hidden

Answer (score 0):

Bien para poder responderte asumiré lo siguiente:

1. Que tienes un selector con *n* opciones a desplegar.
2. Que tienes un campo input oculto del cual esperas tomar el valor para enviar a tu pagina 'ruta.php' una vez que cambias la selección del select

El link adjunto simula el envío de el valor de campo hidden a un servidor externo, como respuesta de este servidor externo recibes el mismo valor que enviaste, es decir lo el .value del campo hidden.

[Ejemplo de envio de valor hidden a servidor externo](https://jsfiddle.net/emersonR/5jky98f4/9/)

Pienso que esto resuelve parte de tu pregunta; si no, házmelo saber.

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada la forma en la que envias los datos a ajax:

```
data:'numeroreporte='+ document.getElementById('numreporte').value
```

Esa linea de codigo esta mal (tranquilo en algun momento me sucedio a mi tambien), para poder enviar datos por medio de ajax es de esta forma:

```
data:{numeroreporte: document.getElementById('numreporte').value}
```

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
 var valorInputHidden = document.getElementById('numreporte').value;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ruta.php',
        data:{numeroreporte: valorInputHidden},
        success:function(data){
          alert (valorInputHidden);
        }
      });
```

Para que entiendas la logica, cree una variable que contendra el valor de tu `input hidden` luego donde envias la data cree otra variable llamada `numeroreporte` esa variable es la que se enviara hacia `ruta.php` utilizo los `:` para darle el valor que tiene la variable `valorInputHidden`

Si aun asi no te funciona, prueba poniendo un `alert()` antes del ajax para ver si cuando el valor del `input hidden` cambia ejecuta la funcion que tienes, En caso ni siquiera se este ejecutando deberiamos ver todo el contexto de como esperar que llegue a ejecutarse el evento `onChange`

Prueba si te funciona de esta manera espero te sirva